# Vue2 - change the route based on store value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to change the route of my components based on a value saved within the vuex store. There are four different template files, saved within different directories (template1, template2 etc). I am pulling the template id from the details store and depending on this value would like to render the component from the correct directory.

For example, if the template value in the store is 2 then load all the `template2/profile` component, if it is three load the `template3/profile` component.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store';


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const setComponent = componentName => {
    return () => import(`../template${store.getters['detailsStore/getTemplate']}/views/${componentName}`)
}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/details'
    },
    {
        path: '/profile',
        name: 'Profile',
        //component: () => import('../template2/views/Profile') // - this is how i was importing the component but couldn't access vuex store
        component: () => setComponent('Profile'),
    },
    {
        path: '/details',
        name: 'Details',
        component: () => setComponent('Details'),
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

I thought creating the `setComponent` function would help,. but i just get a blank page. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Vue2:

Your component is not done loading. This will do it:

```
const asyncComp = async (componentName) => {
  const component = await import(`../template${store.getters['detailsStore/getTemplate']}/views/${componentName}`)
  return component;
};


{
  path: '/profile',
  name: 'Profile',
  component: () => asyncComp('Profile'),
}
```

Vue 3 solution:
Here you will have defineAsyncComponent() available
https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#defineasynccomponent

```
const asyncComp = (compName) => defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`../template${store.getters['detailsStore/getTemplate']}/views/${compName}`);
```